# Converting String to Key for Encryption

Tags: java, android, public-key-encryption, private-key

I'm tring to convert my private key in RSA into a Key from a string, but for some reason it's outputing an system error.

```
static private Key privatekey;
try{
byte[] keyprivBytes = Base64.decode(KeypriString,0);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec specpriv = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyprivBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactorypriv = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
privatekey = keyFactorypriv.generatePrivate(specpriv);  <--(here is where the logcat says the code is broken)
}catch(UnsupportedEncodingException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

in which `keypriString` is the `String` where my private key is.

LogCat:

```
11-12 11:11:20.066 15141-15141/<pakage name> W/System.err: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
11-12 11:11:20.066 15141-15141/<pakage name> W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPrivateKey(OpenSSLKey.java:180)
11-12 11:11:20.076 15141-15141/<pakage name> W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:64)
11-12 11:11:20.076 15141-15141/<pakage name> W/System.err:     at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:187)
11-12 11:11:20.076 15141-15141/<pakage name> W/System.err:     at <pakage name>.Crypto.<init>(Crypto.java:62)
```

Can anybody tell me the problem??

Comment: can you please post all your logcat message

Comment: this is all the logcat related to the problem, the rest is just some logs i did when using the encryption

Comment: but you havent mention what is the exception you get

Comment: @Anjali you were right i was using an tag so i didnt have to search all the code and forgot about it, logcat updated, sorry:/

Comment: you can refer this link for RSA encoding and decoding: http://blog.brainattica.com/working-with-rsa-in-android/

Comment: @Anjali thanks gonna check that out when i got the chance :D

Answer (score 1):

1 : verify step by step with encoding and then decoding, and trace each step to the output: you will see where it crashes

2 : possible errors: Base64.decode gives null because this is not a good base64 string

3 : or Are you confusing between PKCS and X509 ?

You should see 
[Converting Strings to encryption keys and vice versa java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755057/converting-strings-to-encryption-keys-and-vice-versa-java)
, this:
[Java asymmetric encryption: preferred way to store public/private keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441501/java-asymmetric-encryption-preferred-way-to-store-public-private-keys)
, this:
[Create PrivateKey and PublicKey from a String base64 encoding with DER format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454677/create-privatekey-and-publickey-from-a-string-base64-encoding-with-der-format)

Comment: half the problem i think was the confusion between PCKS8 and X509, still trying to resolve the problem