# Generate certificate/private key pair from azure cli

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault

I created a certificate in Azure keyvault. The csr was signed by a CA and I merged the response from the CA back into the keyvault.

I can download the crt using az keyvault download certificate, but how do I now extract the private key so that I can use this certificate for an httpd server.

Using az keyvault secret show gives the value in a base64 string. How can this be used to get the private key?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export the private key:
[Is it possible to get the private key out of Azure Key Vault Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940248/is-it-possible-to-get-the-private-key-out-of-azure-key-vault-keys)

However, you can perhaps generate the private key from your base64:
[Java: How can I generate PrivateKey from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454531/java-how-can-i-generate-privatekey-from-a-string)
+
[Create PrivateKey and PublicKey from a String base64 encoding with DER format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454677/create-privatekey-and-publickey-from-a-string-base64-encoding-with-der-format)

Untested code, but a mix between this and from the above link *might* be the solution.

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String privateKeyString = "**your_base64_string_here**";
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyString);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        System.out.println(privateKey);
    }
}
```